# Where should I use my Google API Key in my code base?

Tags: php, api

```
$.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + addresses[i] + '&sensor=false', null, function (data) {


var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

    position: new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng),
    map: map,
    icon: marker_icon, // This path is the custom pin to be shown. Remove this line and the proceeding comma to use default pin

});


bounds.extend(marker.position);
```

Where should I use my Google API Key?

Is there meant to be a new entry in the marker for an API key?

Comment: has my answer helped you?

Answer (score 1):

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={address}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

[Source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses) - Google Maps API

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

inside your html

source

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/